# Entity Framework 6.1 - Generated SQL has incorect column names

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, webforms

Got and issue with EF 6.1 generating an incorrect query sql and therefore not returning my data.

So EF is generating the following SQL with the **BOLD** showing the incorrect column name of Employee_EmployeeNo which should actually be EmployeeId

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Username] AS [Username], 
    [Limit1].[EmployeeCode] AS [EmployeeCode], 
    [Limit1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
    [Limit1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Limit1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
    [Limit1].[LastMachineUsed] AS [LastMachineUsed], 
    [Limit1].[LastLogonDate] AS [LastLogonDate], 
    [Limit1].[Employee_EmployeeNo] AS [Employee_EmployeeNo], 
    [Limit1].[Username1] AS [Username1], 
    [Limit1].[ObjectName] AS [ObjectName]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
        [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
        [Extent1].[EmployeeCode] AS [EmployeeCode], 
        [Extent1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
        [Extent1].[LastMachineUsed] AS [LastMachineUsed], 
        [Extent1].[LastLogonDate] AS [LastLogonDate], 
        [Extent1].[**Employee_EmployeeNo**] AS [Employee_EmployeeNo], 
        [Extent2].[Username] AS [Username1], 
        [Extent2].[ObjectName] AS [ObjectName], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[tblUser] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tblUserSecurity] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[User_Username] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Username] = [Extent2].[User_Username])
        WHERE [Extent1].[Username] = @p0
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p0 varchar(8000)',@p0='USERNAME'
```

Context

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.EmployeeNo) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.Forename) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.Surname) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
    .HasOptional(Function(e) e.User)



modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .HasKey(Function(e) e.Username)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.Username) _
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.EmployeeNo) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.LastMachineUsed) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.LastMachineUsed) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
    .HasOptional(Function(e) e.Employee) _
    .WithOptionalDependent(Function(s) s.User)



modelBuilder.Entity(Of UserSecurity)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.Username) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of UserSecurity)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.ObjectName) _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of UserSecurity)() _
    .Property(Function(e) e.AccessLevel) _
    .IsFixedLength() _
    .IsUnicode(False)

modelBuilder.Entity(Of UserSecurity)() _
    .HasOptional(Function(e) e.User) _
    .WithOptionalDependent(Function(e) e.UserSecurity)
```

Employee

```
Partial Public Class Employee

    <Key> _
    <StringLength(10)> _
    <Column("EmployeeId")>
    Public Property EmployeeNo As String

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(50)> _
    <Column("Forename")>
    Public Property Forename As String

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(50)> _
    <Column("Surname")>
    Public Property Surname As String

    <Required> _
    <Column("StartDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property StartDate As DateTime

    <Column("EndDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property EndDate As DateTime?

    <Required> _
    <Column("SiteCode")>
    Public Property SiteId As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Site As Site

    Public Overridable Property User As User

End Class
```

User

```
Partial Public Class User

    <Key> _
    <StringLength(50)> _
    <Column("Username")>
    Public Property Username As String

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(10)> _
    <Column("EmployeeCode")>
    Public Property EmployeeNo As String

    <Column("IsActive")>
    Public Property IsActive As Boolean

    <Required> _
    <Column("CreatedDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property CreatedDate As DateTime

    <Column("ModifiedDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property ModifiedDate As DateTime?

    <StringLength(50)> _
    <Column("LastMachineUsed")>
    Public Property LastMachineUsed As String

    <Column("LastLogonDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property LastLogonDate As DateTime?

    Public Overridable Property Employee As Employee

    Public Overridable Property UserSecurity As UserSecurity

End Class
```

User Security

```
Partial Public Class UserSecurity

    <Key> _
    <Column("Username", Order:=0)> _
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Username As String

    <Key> _
    <Column("ObjectName", Order:=1)> _
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property ObjectName As String

    <Column("IsSecurityGroup")>
    Public Property IsSecurityGroup As Boolean

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(1)> _
    <Column("AccessLevel")>
    Public Property AccessLevel As String

    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)> _
    <Column("CheckOrder")>
    Public Property CheckOrder As Integer

    <Column("CreatedDate", TypeName:="date")>
    Public Property CreatedDate As DateTime

    Public Overridable Property User As User

End Class
```

Where m I going wrong? 
Why is EF ignoring the Column Attribute?
Why is it using ClassName_KeyName in the SQL instead of Field Name from the Column Attribute?

Cheers

Comment: I have found that instead of: 

`Return context.Users.Find(Username)`

I can use:

`Return context.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT u.Username, u.EmployeeCode, u.IsActive, u.CreatedDate, u.ModifiedDate, u.LastMachineUsed, u.LastLogonDate, u.EmployeeCode, us.ObjectName FROM tblUser AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN tblUserSecurity AS us ON u.Username = us.Username WHERE (u.Username = @Username)", New SqlParameter("@Username", Username)).SingleOrDefault`

But this is surely defeating the object of using an ORM like EF??

Answer (score 0):

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
.Property(Function(e) e.EmployeeNo) _
.IsUnicode(False)
```

Should be

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
.Property(Function(e) e.EmployeeId) _
.IsUnicode(False)
```

Comment: But I have the Column name specified as 'EmployeeId'


`<Key> _
<StringLength(10)> _
<Column("EmployeeId")>
Public Property EmployeeNo As String`

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how to use a formatted code snippet in this reply lol

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have a foreign key property in your User class so EF is introducing one. By convention it uses _ as the name of the foreign key column.

I'm assuming you are targeting an existing database, otherwise EF would have generated this foreign key column in the database for you.

You could either introduce a foreign key property into the class (and use the  annotation if you want the column to be called something other than the property name). Alternatively, you can always rename the introduced FK without including it in your model - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#IndependentAssociation.

Comment: Hi Rowan, I have tried your suggested but don't seem to have it sorted. 
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of Employee)() _
            .HasOptional(Function(e) e.User) _
            .WithRequired(Function(e) e.Employee) _
            .Map(Function(e) e.MapKey("EmployeeCode")) _
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)

I was hoping that this would have the right impact but I get the following error.

EmployeeCode: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'EmployeeCode' is already defined.